# Bind different functions for just created li elements

Tags: jquery, dynamic-rebinding

I create `li` elements dynamically:

```
<ul>
<li id="1">1</li>
<li id="2">2</li>
<li id="3">3</li>
[...]
</ul>
```

`li_id` is an array value which returns li id (=1,2,3...)

How can I bind different functions to every `li` element in code like this:

```
for (li_id in lids)
{
console.log(li_id);                         
$(li_id).bind('mouseover', function() {
console.log(li_id);
});
}
```

The above doesn't work. How to write it properly?

With `live()` instead of `bind()` it shows the id of the last element of the `lids` array, not 1,2,3...[...], like the `console.log()` outside the `$` statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62

or

[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Given your HTML, the code can be written in two ways.

Using [jQuery 1.4 Event.data](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/) parameter:

```
var lids = [1,2,3];
for (i in lids) {
    var li_id = lids[i];

    $('#' + li_id).bind('mouseover', { id: li_id }, function(ev) {
        console.log(ev.data.id);
    });
}
```

Or, creating a closure with anonymous function:

```
var lids = [1,2,3];
for (i in lids) {
    var li_id = lids[i];

    // an anonymous function 
    (function (id) {
        $('#' + id).bind('mouseover', function() {
            console.log(id);
        });        
    })(li_id); // ...called every time with different id

}
```

I prefer `jQuery Event.data` way in this instance.

Comment: THX!I think that is what I was looking for. But could you show me how to implement this into my code:)?

Answer (score 0):

So with closure the correct answer would be:

```
$(li_id).bind('mouseover', function(val) { 
                             return function() { 
                                console.log(val); 
                             } 
                           }(li_id));
```

But this is only required if you need to pass the value of the loop into the function.

Comment: The selector is minor problem. Merely a typo. The closure problem is  more serious one.

Comment: Thanks Marko, actually I see that now.  I've wrestled with that myself a couple of times so this actually helps me as well.  Thanks!