# javascript: Using the current for-loop counter-value inside a function() { }?

Tags: javascript, scope, copy, for-loop, anonymous-function

on a website i want to do this: (simplified)

```
myHandlers = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  myHandlers.push(new Handler({
    handlerName: 'myHandler'+i, // works, e.g. ->myHandler1, 2, 3 etc.
    handlerFunc: function(bla) { /*...*/ alert(i); } // doesn't work,all return 7
  }
}
```

I could set the counter as another attribute of my Handler (which would copy the current value) and use it inside my function, but I guess, there is also a way to actually copy this value, no?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443902/bind-different-functions-for-just-created-li-elements

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When *handlerFunc* is called, the `i` inside the function refers to the `i` of the `for` loop. But that `i` does probably not have the same value any more.

Use a closure to bind the current value of `i` in the scope of an anonymous function:

```
handlerFunc: (function(i) { return function(bla) { /*...*/ alert(i); }; })(i)
```

Here an anonymous function `(function(i) { … })(i)` is used and called immediately. This function binds the value of `i` of the `for` loop to the local `i`. That `i` is then independent from the `i` of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myHandlers = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  myHandlers.push(new Handler({
    handlerName: 'myHandler'+i, // works, e.g. ->myHandler1, 2, 3 etc.
    handlerFunc: 
    (function(i) { 
     return function(blah) { 
         alert(i) 
     }
     })(i)
  }))
}
```

Use a closure to bind the `i` so the value stays intact

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `i` in the functions is the same variable as `i` outside the functions.  As `i` is incremented in the loop, so is it incremented within the functions.  As a result, if the functions are called after the loop has finished, they will all alert "7".

You need to create a new variable with appropriate scope and copy the value of `i` into it.

Something like this would create the desired effect.

```
...
var pushHandler = function(i) {
  myHandlers.push(new Handler({
    handlerName: 'myHandler'+i, // works, e.g. ->myHandler1, 2, 3 etc.
    handlerFunc: function(bla) { /*...*/ alert(i); } // doesn't work,all return 7
  }
}
...
for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  pushHandler(i);
}

...
```

Comment: Sorry to comment on this 6 years after the fact, but I just came across this problem while writing some node.  I prefer this method, as (at least for me) is much more understandable than the above method of pushing an interpreted method passing in `i`.  I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around the whole thing.  This is very simple, concise, and understandable.