# jQuery: form inside while loop

Tags: jquery

I have a form inside a while loop in PHP. There is action="javascript:block_grade($id)", but when i alert(id) or alert(lvl) in the block_grade function, I receive the same numbers from all the the loops?

This is inside my loop:

```
echo '<form action="javascript:block_grade('.$show['id'].')" method="post">';
echo 'Change blockgrade: ';
echo '<input type="text" name="lvl" size="1" value="'.$show['lvl'].'">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Save">';
echo '</form>';
```

This is my function at bottom:

```
<script>
function block_grade ( id ) {
var lvl = $('input[name=lvl]').val();
alert(lvl);
alert(id);
}
</script>
```

How can I solve this, and is there any more effective way than this, maybe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript: Using the current for-loop counter-value inside a function() { }?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448195/javascript-using-the-current-for-loop-counter-value-inside-a-function)

Comment: @pst I don't think it relates to closures. More like he expects the jQuery to magically know which element he requires.

Comment: He passes `id` as a parameter to `block_grade()`. No magic involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd prefer to see JavaScript attach the event handler directly and then you can easily do things relative to the form.

```
echo '<input type="text" name="lvl" size="1" value="'.$show['lvl'].'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" size="1" value="'.$show['id'].'">';
```

Then:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var id = $(this).find('input[name=id]').val();
    var lvl = $(this).find('input[name=lvl]').val(); 
});
```

Among other advantages, this frees up the `action` property so you can fill in a script that can directly process this request without JavaScript if necessary.

But more to the point (of your original question), it ensures that you're looking at the ***correct*** `lvl` field, and not just the first `lvl` field jQuery happens to come across in the DOM.

Comment: Should i have my JS inside the loop? Else im still getting these same results? Or is there a way..

Comment: No, that JavaScript is self-sufficient.  You do not need any other JavaScript anywhere on the page to make that work. If you're getting the same results with this setup, something's wrong with your PHP — it's outputting the same values for `lvl` and `id` for every form.

Comment: Just saw in the html output (view source) It shows the right values for id and lvl in the value="" there.

Comment: Then either your markup is screwy somewhere or you have an entirely separate piece of JavaScript interfering. My best guess: you've got a `<form>` tag wrapped around the entire collection of forms. The HTML validator should catch that.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't even know that it's possible to set the action of a form to "javascript: ...". I always use the `onsubmit` event.

Anyway, for `lvl` it is no wonder you get always the same because `val()` gives the value of the first element in the set. The set contains *all* the `input`s in the whole page.

However, for `id` you should get the correct value. Maybe you should show the final HTML that is generated.

Comment: the final html (source) is giving me right results.. I believe its because the JS is outside the loop?

Comment: No, that's ok. If you are calling it like `block_grade(1)`, `block_grade(2)`, `block_grade(3)` it should alert "1", "2" and then "3" for `id`.

Comment: Okay, I still can't get any other values out from the other elements