# JavaScript Closure Issue... Scoping?

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm trying to expand my modest level of JavaScript skills by learning how to use closures. In the code below, I thought I'd see console.log output counting down from 3 to 0. Instead, I'm getting -1, -1, -1, -1.

I know I'm dealing with scoping issues, but that's about it. What's missing? How should this be properly written, and why?

```
function closure_count_test (number)   
{    
    for (var x = 0; x <= number; x += 1)   
    {  
        setTimeout(function() {console.log(number - x);}, x * 1000);  
    }  
}  

closure_count_test(3);
```

Comment: Yes. There is only **one** variable `x`. I gave a -1 because you know what the issue is (something related to "closure" and "scope"); and should have thus been able to find a duplicate.

Comment: because `x` inside your callback references to the same `x` in `closure_count_test`. The value of `x` is obtained when your callback is called.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-a-for-loop-and-pass-i-as-value , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448195/javascript-using-the-current-for-loop-counter-value-inside-a-function?lq=1 , etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doesn't JavaScript support closures with local variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643542/doesnt-javascript-support-closures-with-local-variables)

Comment: Thanks for the replies, everyone. I've been using SO as a resource for years, it's good to get constructive feedback to my first post.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct. The problem is that setTimout only considers the latest value of the variables. So the setTimout always get x = 0 since it is the last in the loop.

you can see your desired output if you remove the setTimout function.

Comment: The code in setTimeout only "considers" the *current* value of the variable; it just so happens to be last set the value during the last iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

this works because x being to be localised inside one more closure

```
function closure_count_test(number) {
    for (var x = 0; x <= number; x++)  ( // not need {} as here is only one operator
      function (x) { //Now x - local variable in anonymous function
        return setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(number - x);
        }, x * 1000);
      }(x) // pass x to anonymous function as argument
    ); 
}

closure_count_test(3);
```

Comment: This won't work because 1) the `console.log` will happen *immediately*, and 2) `setTimeout` will be passed `undefined` as the callback. (I didn't down-vote, but that is why this answer is wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

How scoping works in basic words is, it makes variables of a main function, that are referenced in nested functions stay after function ends, and all of these functions can later access them.
In provided example x is a variable defined in the main function, and all nested functions will later be able to reference it. By that time the value of x will be number+1, so your result makes perfect sense. To workaround that, you must avoid referencing the variable of the main function. Here's the normal technique:

```
function closure_count_test (number)   
{    
   for (var x = 0; x <= number; x += 1)   
   {  
       setTimeout(function(x) {
          return function() {console.log(number - x);}
       } (x), x * 1000);
   }  
}
```

What you do here, is you call several nested functions, which have their own x copied as an argument, and each of these have one nested function that will reference that argument via scope.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is iterated by the `for` loop, but the function in `setTimeout` uses the variable `x`, which is not interpolated at the time the function is created.  This causes it to use whatever the final value of `x` is (because the `setTimeout`s execute after the loop completes).

In order to get around this, you have to pass the value of x as it is to the callback of `setTimeout`.  You can call a function that returns another function (the new callback):

```
for (var x = 0; x <= number; x += 1) {
    setTimeout(
        (function (x) {
            return function () { console.log(number - x) };
        })(x)
    , x * 1000);  
}
```

This passes `x` from the outer scope with its current value to the inner scope.  The inner function uses whatever value `x` was when the function was created.

A function is returned to work properly with `setTimeout`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/QhA3a/